# Having some issues with mod rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hyperlink

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^profile/(\w+)/*$ ./index.php?page=showuser&username=$1
```

Okay, so I have this code that will rewrite my URL exactly how it want it to (sitename/profile/username).

Now let's say I want to access only (sitename/profile/). What rule do I have to write in order for that to work and not give me an error?

I am new to mod rewrite so I am sorry if this question seem stupid to some of you.

Comment: What should the target be if there's no username parameter?

Comment: Edited the first post. Sorry.

Comment: Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't RewriteEngine On need to go before Options +FollowSymLinks?

Comment: As I said, I am new to this and on the tutorials I read the syntax was exactly like this one. Now I am not sure if that's the correct way or not. However, could you please answer my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^profile/$ ./index.php?page=profile [L,NC]
```

The dollar at the end matches the end of the URL. In this case, there cannot be anything else after `profile/`

Comment: Tried your code but it gives me a "Access Forbidden" error and the url becomes http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/folder_name/

Comment: works for me, it could conflict with some other rule, it's a good idea to add [L,NC] to the end of the rule, L stands for Last, NC for non-case.

Comment: Can you post your complete ruleset?

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks  
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
    RewriteRule ^profile/(\w+)/*$ ./index.php?page=showuser&id=$1
    RewriteRule ^profile/$ ./index.php?page=showuser [L,NC]

Comment: works here, do you have a slash at the end of the url? the rule includes it

Comment: `RewriteRule ^profile/$ ./index.php?page=showuser&username=
RewriteRule ^profile$ ./index.php?page=showuser&username=` Added that in Now website_name/profile/ works as I want it to but website_name/profile without slash at the end gives me that nasty error.